# Passing parameters from script to XSL

Tags: xpath, parameter-passing, xslt-2.0

Using XSLT2 with the latest Saxon HE.

I'm trying to pass multiple coordinate parameters from a script to XSL in order to filter results based on a location boundary box

Script:

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -s:litter_bins.xml -o:"bins.xml" -xsl:"Split xml coords.xsl" Coord_2=51.3725 Coord_4=51.3751 Coord_1=-2.3615 Coord_3=-2.3572
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">   
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>   

    <xsl:param name="Coord_2" select="Coord_2"/>
    <xsl:param name="Coord_4" select="Coord_4"/>
    <xsl:param name="Coord_1" select="Coord_1"/>
    <xsl:param name="Coord_3" select="Coord_3"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node[@lat[ . &lt; $Coord_2 or . &gt; $Coord_4 ] or @lon[ . &lt; $Coord_1 or . &gt; $Coord_3]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="JOSM"/>
```

However if I hard code the coordinates into the `match` xpath, it returns the expected results.

Xpath:

```
  <xsl:template match="node[@lat[ . &lt; 51.3725 or . &gt; 51.3751 ] or @lon[ . &lt; -2.3615 or . &gt; -2.3572]]"/>
```

Results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="JOSM">
   <node id="-102973" visible="true" lat="51.37283499216" lon="-2.359890029">
      <tag k="date_creat" v="17/07/2014 07:59:04 AM UTC"/>
      <tag k="form_recor" v="888"/>
   </node>
<snip...>
</osm>
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Does it work if you add a type declaration of e.g. `<xsl:param name="Coord_2"  as="xs:double"/>` to the parameters (Needs a namespace declaration `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` of course)? Try to first check with `xsl:message` or similar that the parameter values are passed correctly from your command shell to Saxon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare a numeric type for the parameters e.g. `<xsl:param name="Coord_2" as="xs:double"/>` or `<xsl:param name="Coord_2" as="xs:decimal"/>`. Of course for that your stylesheet needs to declare `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` as a namespace declaration on the root element.

Without a numeric type I think the comparison will be of two `xs:untypedAtomic` values and then https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-general-comparisons demands

> If both atomic values are instances of xs:untypedAtomic, then the
>   values are cast to the type xs:string

and then the string comparison of negative numbers fails to give you the wanted result.

Comment: Correct, without a declared type the parametes will be treated as xs:untypedAtomic values and will be compared as strings.